# How to position a UIAlertView

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I've tried using this

```
  message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Incorrect!"
                                             message:wrongString
                                            delegate:self
                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"Try Again"
                                   otherButtonTitles:nil];
        if(adjustIncorrect) {
            NSLog(@"Showing adjusted");
           message.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation( 0.00, 300.00);
        }
        [message show];
```

It is printing out Showing Adjusted, so I know that's not the issue. But the alert isn't moving no matter what numbers I put in. I've seen a few posts saying with the newer versions of iOs this might not work, any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't do it: "The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.". You should not access any private properties in UIAlertView directly as well as you should not subclass UIAlertView - this is clearly stated by Apple and is likely to lead to a rejection of your App during revision when sent for publication to the Apple Store. The same applies to UIActionSheet.

Instead you should look into **implementing your own alert view to be loaded modally when needed**.